# Cython linking fails due to 'from __future__ import division' must occur at the beginning of the file

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I want to create a single cython extension that aggregates multiple python files.

For that I created a .pyx file:

```
include a.py
include b.py
include c.py
...
```

Compilation works, but linking fails with the following error:

```
from __future__ import division
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

./b.py:169:31: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

The reasons is that the given statement is indeed not at the beginning of the merged file (as the include statements in the .pyx file just do textual merging).

How can I work around this? For instance, how can I do conditional compilation and e.g. omit that statement in `b.py` if this is compiled in cython? It should still be included if it is run as pure python module.

Comment: Conditional compilation syntax will raise SyntaxError under regular python. I'm afraid there is no solution except generating merged file by yourself.

Comment: Yes i know. However I expexted that a Python function 'is_compiled_or_run_with_cython()' would exist.